# Is there a way to loop over all outputs from stageDependencies in Azure DevOps?

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I want to loop over all the outputs of dependent stages and check if any of them are set to a specific value which would indicate there was a problem. Is this possible, and if so, how?

I'm having trouble finding any relevant documentation on `stageDependencies` outside of using them in job conditions. I know the code below doesn't work, but I've tried a few variations on this and I'm not even seeing the `stageDependencies` object.

```
- task: PowerShell@2
  displayName: Check for Failures
    inputs:
      targetType: inline
      script: |
        foreach ($dependency in $[stageDependencies]) {
          foreach ($job in $dependency) {
            foreach ($output in $job.outputs) {
              if ("$output" -eq "Started") {
                write-host "##vso[task.logissue type=error]Task failed in a previous step"
              }
            }
          }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Michael, any update on this, have you checked my answer? Does it answer your question?

Answer (score 3):

Also needed to get list of all variables from previous stages, and in result came up with solution by converting `stageDependencies` to JSON in pipeline and then back to object in Powershell.

Here is the example of pipeline that sets 2 variables in first stage and reads them in second stage by initial variable name - `someVariable` and `another.variable.with.dots` without need to use stage/job/step names.

```
trigger:
  - master

stages:
  - stage: SetVars
    jobs:
      - job: SetVarsJob
        steps:
          - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=someVariable;isOutput=true]firstVarValue"
          - script: echo "##vso[task.setvariable variable=another.variable.with.dots;isOutput=true]secondVarValue"
  - stage: ReadVars
    dependsOn: SetVars
    jobs:
      - job: ReadVars
        variables:
          stageDependenciesSerialized: $[convertToJson(stageDependencies)]
        steps:
          - powershell: |
              # extract only initial variables as hashtable
              function ExtractHashtableByVariableNames {
                  param ( [Parameter(Position=0)] [string] $stageDependenciesJson )

                  $result = @{}
                  $stageDependencies = $stageDependenciesJson | ConvertFrom-Json
                  foreach($stage in $stageDependencies.psobject.Properties) {
                      foreach($job in $stage.Value.psobject.Properties) {
                          foreach($step in $job.Value.outputs.psobject.Properties) {
                              $varName = $step.Name.Substring($step.Name.IndexOf('.') + 1)
                              $result[$varName] = $step.Value
                          }
                      }
                  }
                  return $result
              }
              $myHashtable = ExtractHashtableByVariableNames '$(stageDependenciesSerialized)'
              Write-Host $myHashtable["someVariable"]
              Write-Host $myHashtable["another.variable.with.dots"]
```

In the result it prints

```
firstVarValue
secondVarValue
```

Comment: btw, if need to keep reference to name of stage/job/step, can use $stage.Name, $job.Name or $step.Name in the Powershell loop.
Also please note that stageDependencies JSON seem to have stages sorted in alphabetical order, not in the execution order - so last one doesn't mean the previous one.

Answer (score 0):

The pipeline can output variables through the logging command, but the variables can only be strings:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/process/variables?view=azure-devops&tabs=yaml%2Cbatch#set-variables-in-scripts

> All variables set by this method are treated as strings.

It is not difficult to parse a string and put it into an array, just use the function(split()) that comes with the string type to split and restore.

Here is an example:

```
trigger:
- none

# 1
stages:
- stage: s1
  displayName: setvars
  jobs:
    - job: testJob
      steps:
        - task: PowerShell@2
          name: setvar
          inputs:
            targetType: 'inline'
            script: |
              # logic here. For example you get the vars and put it into this format:
              $testvars = "testvar1,testvar2,testvar3" 
              Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=outputvars;isOutput=true]$testvars"


# 2
- stage: s2
  displayName: getvars
  dependsOn: s1  
  variables:
    vars: $[ stageDependencies.s1.testJob.outputs['setvar.outputvars'] ]
  jobs:
    - job:
      steps:  
      - task: PowerShell@2
        inputs:
          targetType: 'inline'
          script: |
            $varsArr = "$(vars)".Split(',')
            foreach ($var in $varsArr)
            {
              Write-Host "$var`r`n"
              if($var -eq 'testvar1')
              {
                Write-Host 'The value is correct.'
              }
            }
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: This is not exactly what I need. For your #1 above, I have a matrix of jobs, where the same job is run but on different build configurations (e.g. debug, release, Linux, Windows), and so I was hoping to look at all the output variables without having to specifically go through  stageDependencies.s1.windows_release.outputs['setvar.outputvars'], stageDependencies.s1.linux_release.outputs['setvar.outputvars'], stageDependencies.s1.windows_debug.outputs['setvar.outputvars'], etc.